# How to turn off DEBUGs in the spark-shell inside the bigdatauniversity/spark docker image?

Tags: apache-spark

The `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell` in the [bigdatauniversity/spark docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/bigdatauniversity/spark/) is much too verbose which makes it difficult to work with.

How can I turn off the debugging in the `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured how to do this so posting the answer for other users.

For me, I simply had to do:

```
cp /opt/ibm/spark-1.3.1_IBM_1-bin-2.6.0/conf/log4j.properties.template \
   /opt/ibm/spark-1.3.1_IBM_1-bin-2.6.0/conf/log4j.properties
```

You will need to change the above path to reflect the version of spark running in your container.

Answer (score 2):

For Application level log Management :

**in standalone App - code**

```
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger
    import org.apache.log4j.Level

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

       Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
       Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
       // rest code comes here
     }
```

**In Spark-shell**

```
scala>import org.apache.log4j.Logger
scala>import org.apache.log4j.Level
scala>Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
scala>Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```